# Swift: Detecting iOS Keyboard text replacement in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

iOS has a built-in functionality where user can set up text replacements in

> Settings > General > Keyboards > Text Replacement

In my Swift iOS app's UITextField, I need to know when user used this text replacement so I can take appropriate action. My instinct was to use

```
func textField(tf: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
```

but interestingly, this function is not invoked on this kind of text replacement, are there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: I just tried it, and `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` is actually invoked when i typed in "omw ", which was replaced with "On my way! " when I entered the space character. I tried on the iPhone 6s Plus (9.3) and iPhone 4s (8.1) simulators.

Comment: Maybe in the didendediting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function in this setting and it does see the text expansion.  I tested with:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        print(string.characters.count)

        return true
  }
```

You can watch the character count jump immediately after the text expansion.

Make sure your textField is hooked up with an IBOutlet and you have set the class as a delegate (`textField.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`).

Once you see this working you can of course identify text expansion and handle any way you wish.

Comment: Turned out, I was checking for `.text` value of the `textField` in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` which is too early.

Comment: Actually, I should also mention that it was not working for me because I was trying to suppress whitespaces at the same time through `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` which was blocking the text replacement notification.